# Ansible ansible.builtin.url module "Name does not resolve" error

Tags: debugging, url, module, ansible

I am trying to use the `ansible.builtin.url` module to fetch the contents of a remote file on my remote server. I am using one of the examples in the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/url_lookup.html) page of the module, but **occasionally** I am getting the `Name does not resolve` error. I am saying occasionally because this behaviour is not consistent. Sometimes I get the results, sometimes I get the error...

How do you suggest I debug this error?

### Ansible task

```
- name: url lookup splits lines by default
  debug: msg="{{item}}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('url', 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json', wantlist=True) }}"
```

### Playbook output

```
TASK [url lookup splits lines by default] *********************************************************************************************
fatal: [my.domain.name]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'url'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Failed lookup url for https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json : <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name does not resolve>"}
```

### Ansible version

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.6 (default, Oct  5 2020, 00:23:48) [GCC 10.2.0]
```

### Python packages versions

```
$ pip3 list
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
appdirs                1.4.3               
attrs                  19.3.0              
Automat                0.8.0               
blinker                1.4                 
certifi                2019.11.28          
chardet                3.0.4               
Click                  7.0                 
cloud-init             20.3                
colorama               0.4.3               
command-not-found      0.3                 
configobj              5.0.6               
constantly             15.1.0              
cryptography           2.8                 
dbus-python            1.2.16              
distlib                0.3.0               
distro                 1.4.0               
distro-info            0.23ubuntu1         
entrypoints            0.3                 
fail2ban               0.11.1              
filelock               3.0.12              
httplib2               0.14.0              
hyperlink              19.0.0              
idna                   2.8                 
importlib-metadata     1.5.0               
incremental            16.10.1             
Jinja2                 2.10.1              
jsonpatch              1.22                
jsonpointer            2.0                 
jsonschema             3.2.0               
keyring                18.0.1              
language-selector      0.1                 
launchpadlib           1.10.13             
lazr.restfulclient     0.14.2              
lazr.uri               1.0.3               
MarkupSafe             1.1.0               
more-itertools         4.2.0               
netifaces              0.10.4              
oauthlib               3.1.0               
pexpect                4.6.0               
pip                    20.0.2              
pyasn1                 0.4.2               
pyasn1-modules         0.2.1               
PyGObject              3.36.0              
PyHamcrest             1.9.0               
pyinotify              0.9.6               
PyJWT                  1.7.1               
pymacaroons            0.13.0              
PyNaCl                 1.3.0               
pyOpenSSL              19.0.0              
pyrsistent             0.15.5              
pyserial               3.4                 
python-apt             2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.1
python-debian          0.1.36ubuntu1       
PyYAML                 5.3.1               
requests               2.22.0              
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0               
SecretStorage          2.3.1               
service-identity       18.1.0              
setuptools             45.2.0              
simplejson             3.16.0              
six                    1.14.0              
sos                    4.0                 
ssh-import-id          5.10                
systemd-python         234                 
Twisted                18.9.0              
ubuntu-advantage-tools 20.3                
ufw                    0.36                
unattended-upgrades    0.1                 
urllib3                1.25.8              
virtualenv             20.0.17             
wadllib                1.3.3               
wheel                  0.34.2              
zipp                   1.0.0               
zope.interface         4.7.1
```

PS: Running `dig ip-ranges.amazonaws.com` on the target machine returns this output:

```
$ dig ip-ranges.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> ip-ranges.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16015
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-ranges.amazonaws.com.   IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ip-ranges.amazonaws.com. 900    IN  CNAME   d3mduebighmd0u.cloudfront.net.
d3mduebighmd0u.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   13.224.93.97
d3mduebighmd0u.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   13.224.93.6
d3mduebighmd0u.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   13.224.93.36
d3mduebighmd0u.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   13.224.93.58

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 19 11:42:03 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 159
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? If yes, did you configure that proxy in your local controller environement ? If not behind a proxy, what is the output of `dig ip-ranges.amazonaws.com` or `nslookup ip-ranges.amazonaws.com` launched on your controller machine (with the same user you use for the playbook) ?

Comment: No, I am not behind a proxy. My controller machine is a docker container and when I open a shell into it and run the dig command I get a similar output as the one I described in the issue above (I cannot post the output in the comments here, it's to large). My remote machine is on Exoscale.

Comment: On your controller, what do you get running `ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ lookup('dig', 'ip-ranges.amazonaws.com') }}"`? Make sure the `dnspython` module is available in your environment before running the command.

Comment: I get `localhost | SUCCESS => {"msg": "13.224.93.97,13.224.93.36,13.224.93.6,13.224.93.58"}`

Comment: and what about `ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ lookup('url', 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json', wantlist=True) }}"` If this works as well, you will have to find out what is the difference between this ad-hoc command and your playbook.

Comment: I see the same behavior here. With the first run, it worked. Running it a second time, I get the same error. I tried running it another 10 times, with different time intervals in between, always failing. Only the first run worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with the OS version the controller was running. Changing it from `alpine:edge` to `alpine:3.12.1` fixed the problem. This issue helped: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/539